# How do I replace version "*" in Cargo.toml with version numbers from Cargo.lock?

Tags: rust, dependencies, version, rust-cargo

When I'm developing a Rust project, I usually use `foo-crate = "*"` for dependency versions unless I have a reason to pick a particular version.

Before sharing a project, I want to update the `"*"` dependency version numbers in Cargo.toml to those found in Cargo.lock.  i.e. I want the `"*"` version number to be replaced with what I'm successfully using in the project.

When I only have two or three dependencies, it's not a concern to do this manually.

Now, I'm regularly depending on a dozen or more crates.

Is there an automated way to move version numbers from Cargo.lock to Cargo.toml?

Comment: I just use `cargo add` from the beginning.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I copy a lot of dependencies from examples but change their versions to "*" to get the latest versions.  I hadn't come across `cargo add` - I'll start using that.

Comment: There is this [plugin](https://crates.io/crates/cargo-stabilize) called cargo-stabilize might help. It doesn't look like it is maintained but I tried, it worked for a simple case. I'd keep my original cargo.toml and replace the dependencies section with the values from produced one.

Comment: @ÖmerErden Thanks, if you make this an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: *"I usually use `foo-crate = "*"` for dependency versions unless I have a reason to pick a particular version"* - I would question that workflow. How do you develop code of you don't develop it against a known API? The proper workflow is to pick one specific version when installing (happens automatically when installing with `cargo add`), and then your code is automatically compatible with that version and all semver compatible updates. That's exactly what the [semver](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/semver.html) concept is for.

Comment: *"unless I have a reason to pick a particular version"* - the reason is that you want to actually use that dependency. So the very moment you make your first call to it is the moment when you need a specific version.

Maybe this is a misconception of yours - if you add a specific version in `Cargo.toml`, it does **not** mean that exactly that version is installed. It means that this is the **minimal required version** that you need. Updates of that dependency will be applied, unless the new version is no longer semver compatible (e.g. an API breaking major change)

Comment: So you always want to specify a version (ideally a full `a.b.c` version, not just an `a.x`) because then, cargo knows that your crate will work correctly if at least that version is installed. If there are other dependencies that also depend on the same crate, then a version is selected that is compatible with all of the depending crates. This means, if you don't specify a minimal version, a different dependency might choose a really old version for you and break your code. `"*"` means that your code would also be compatible with `0.0.1-alpha.0` of that dependency, which I highly doubt.